# Hilbert modular forms and Hecke operators over Q

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, arithmetic-geometry

Let F be a totally real field. We know that we can define a Hecke operator $T_\mathfrak{m}$ on the space of Hilbert modular forms over $F$, say with some level structure, for any ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ that is coprime to the level.

Let's say we have two eigenforms $f_1$ and $f_2$ whose Hecke eigenvalues agree on $T_p$ for all rational primes prime to the level. Does it follow that the two forms are the say by some sort of multiplicity theorem?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't follow. Take e.g. the case where F is real quadratic. The space of Hilbert modular forms has an involution coming from the action of the nontrivial automorphism $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(F/\mathbf{Q})$, and this interchanges the Hecke eigenvalues at $\mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{m}^\sigma$. So the Hecke eigenvalues at rational primes cannot distinguish $f$ from its image $f^\sigma$ under this involution.